# Probability of finding a Markov process in a small ball, given that it is in a larger ball

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process

I stumbled upon the following problem, which intuitively makes sense but I don't know how to rigorously show it. Let $Y$ be a continuous Markov process with values in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Fix $N\in\mathbb{N}$ and $T\geq 0$ What can be said about the ratio

$$\frac{\mathbb{P}^0(\vert Y_T\vert\leq \epsilon )}{\mathbb{P}^0(\vert Y_T\vert\leq \frac{N-1}{N}\epsilon )}=\mathbb{P}^0\bigg(\vert Y_T\vert<\frac{N-1}{N}\epsilon\bigg\vert \vert Y_T\vert<\epsilon\bigg)^{-1}$$ as $\epsilon\downarrow 0$?

In particular, is there an upper bound?

Comment: How does the transition kernel look like ? Is it translation invariant ? Rotation invariant ?

Comment: @justt In my case $Y_t$ is the sum of a symmetric Markov process $X$ (for which we have upper and lower heat kernel bounds similar to those for BM), a smooth drift term $\gamma$ and the integral up to time $t$ of $\gamma$ against $X$. So not too nice... The drift is deterministic and only depends on time $t$